# red5 live stream always dropped frames

Tags: actionscript, red5, live-streaming, netstream

I have a live stream site build on red5 server and when i subscribe, the live video seems to drop frames.

I am using the oflademo for my rtmp application.

Here is the actionscript I use for the camera setting:

**Broadcast**

```
// setup cam
cam = Camera.get();
// setting dimensions and framerate
cam.setMode(320, 240, 15, false);
// set quality
cam.setQuality(0,0);
cam.setKeyFrameInterval(48);
```

Subscribe is the same as broadcast.

Can anyone give a hand.

Comment: If you're going to setQuality to 0,0; I would suggest not setting it at all

Answer (score 1):

in general dropped frames (or gaps in the audio signal) are a sign for bandwidth issues.

These are our settings, frames are never dropped (if the bandwidth is okay):

```
cam.setMode(160, 120, 30, true);
cam.setQuality(0,90);
```

We have never been using "cam.setKeyFrameInterval(48);". I would not set this value at all. I would not force the video compression any value. Do you have a reason why you think 48 is a good value for it?

Sebastian

Comment: [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/hpdocs/help.html?content=00000135.html)is the desc about the keyFrameInterval. I think he do 48th frame as a keyframe, does 160x120 is too small what's the video frame of yours.

Comment: Our video frame is resizable. 160x120 is just an example. It might be 320x240. It depends what the user selects for video pod size. I know what keyFrameInterval means but what do you try to achieve with it? I am not sure if Red5 does interpret this value at all or what effect it might have.

Comment: If you're going to set the keyframe interval, I suggest using this formula (10 * fps) to determine the value; in your case above it would be 150.